# How to count the element nodes

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, sax

I have posted an XML file below, and what I want is to count all of the elements, where an XML node is named "node", using xpath. I wrote the following code and i expected to get the result `9`, since there are 9 node elements called "node", but the result I get is different and shown below. Could you please help with that?

**results**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBase.ensureSizeOfIndex(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBase.indexNode(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.dom2dtm.DOM2DTM.addNode(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.dom2dtm.DOM2DTM.nextNode(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBaseTraversers$IndexedDTMAxisTraverser.getNextIndexed(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.dtm.ref.DTMDefaultBaseTraversers$DescendantTraverser.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.DescendantIterator.nextNode(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.LocPathIterator.getLength(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.axes.NodeSequence.getLength(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.functions.FuncCount.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPath.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.eval(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathImpl.evaluate(Unknown Source)
at com.example.xpath_01.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:40)
```

**code**:

```
Document document = builder.parse(new FileInputStream("c:\\bremen.xml"));
XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xPath =  xpathFactory.newXPath();

String expr0 = "count(//node)";
xPath.compile(expr0);
String s = (String) xPath.evaluate(expr0, document, XPathConstants.NODE);

System.out.println(s);
```

**xml**:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<osm>
<node id="125799" lat="53.0749415" lon="8.7868047"/>
<node id="125800" lat="53.071932" lon="8.7840591"/>
<node id="125801" lat="53.0705997" lon="8.7818627">
<node id="125802" lat="53.067967" lon="8.7789767"/>
<node id="125803" lat="53.066404" lon="8.7776205"/>
<node id="125805" lat="53.0655804" lon="8.7768297"/>
<node id="125806" lat="53.0633485" lon="8.7743991"/>
<node id="125807" lat="53.0623592" lon="8.7728449"/>
<node id="125808" lat="53.0614152" lon="8.7701245"/>
```

Comment: Double s = ( Double) xPath.evaluate(expr0, document, XPathConstants.NUMBER);

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque when i used  XPathConstants.NUMBER it works only when i specify String expr0 = "count(osm//node)"; and if i just used String expr0 = "count(//node)"; it gives me an error...can u please tell me why?

Comment: I don't know maybe "node" is a keyword and the xpaht interpreter goes to infiny loop...

Comment: Looks suspiciously like a bug to me. Is this really a very small XML document? I don't think you should be using XPathConstants.NODE as the third arg of evaluate when the expression returns a number, but that seems unrelated. Try a different XPath engine.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `OutOfMemoryError`. it means the xml file is big to fit in memory.

So instead of using DOM and XPath, use SAX as shown below:

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import java.io.File;

/**
 * @author Santhosh Kumar Tekuri
 */
public class NodeCountingHandler extends DefaultHandler{
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException{
        count = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException{
        if(localName.equals("node"))
            ++count;
    }

    public static int getNodeCount(File file) throws Exception{
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        NodeCountingHandler handler = new NodeCountingHandler();
        factory.newSAXParser().parse(file, handler);
        return handler.count;
    }
}
```

Now to get node count, simply do:

```
int nodeCount = NodeCountingHandler.getNodeCount(file);
```

Comment: but can i use xpath with sax?? i thought xpath could only be used in combination with dom

Comment: if you are interested using xpath with sax, you can try http://jlibs.in/xmldog/XMLDog.html. BTW I am the owner of this project